# Linked Server Certificate issue

Tags: sql-server, certificate, linked-server

I have 2 SQL Servers(2017): A and B.
Server_A does not have a certificate and encryption is not enabled.
Server_B has a certificate and encryption is enabled.

While logged onto Server_A:
SELECT * FROM [Server_B].MyDB.dbo.MyTable -- This works

While logged onto Server_B:
SELECT * FROM [Server_A].SomeDb.dbo.AnyTable -- This fails with the error:

"*OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "Server_A" returned message "Client unable to establish connection".
Msg -2146893019, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.*"

This seems backwards to me. I would think that the first query would fail because it originates from a SQL Server with no certificate. Instead the SQL Server with a certificate fails when communicating to a "no certificate" server.
I would like to understand why this is failing in this way.
Also, what do I have to do to make the 2nd query succeed? I suspect installing a certificate on Server_A will solve this. Does this sound correct?

Answer (score 0):

Install a certificate on server A does not solve the problem.

If you don't have the certificate you can get the databases list with the relative certificate with the below query [see this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/92080/query-to-list-encryption-certificate-for-databases)

```
use master;
go

select
    database_name = d.name,
    dek.encryptor_type,
    cert_name = c.name
from sys.dm_database_encryption_keys dek
left join sys.certificates c
on dek.encryptor_thumbprint = c.thumbprint
inner join sys.databases d
on dek.database_id = d.database_id;
```

Once you have obtained the certificate name you can [BACKUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it to a folder.

From here you must know a little bit about certificates.
Each certificate has an "Issuer" (someone who signs the certificate) and/or a chain (intermediate path signed by an ancestor intermediate, and so on) when you query the db, your PC read the certificate and verify the chain.

The error says:

> The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted."

This means: "I don't trust the certificate because it is emitted by someone whom I don't trust"

An exception is for a self-signed certificate where the issuer of the certificate is itself and it has no chain (single node).

You must *open* the certificate and see the chain.

On windows:

1. If is self-signed, install the certificate on "Trusted root certificate authority"
2. If is NOT self-signed you must lookup for the chain certificate and install it on "Trusted root certificate authority"

On Linux, I don't remember exactly and you must look on google about it.

Comment: Ooops! I was mistaken. My answer did not fix the issue. I am still getting the error.

Comment: Solved: In SQL Server Configuration Manager I had to set the CLIENT protocol to Force Encryption and Trust Server Certificate. I even deleted the imported certificate and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Max,

Thank you for the reply. Your answer regarded certificates at the database level. Indeed when I query the sys.certificates system catalog it returns the certificates used for TDE encryption. However, the certificates I am using are for Transport Layer Security (TLS) encryption which are at the server level.
But your answer highlighted the error "*The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted*" and this got me thinking along different lines. AND you mentioned I needed to 'open' the certificate. When I opened the cert that I had exported it stated it could not be verified. Turns out I exported it incorrectly. My 2nd export attempt worked.

As I re-read the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) I also realized I missed the step of granting the SQL Server service account read permission. Once I did that the Linked Server successfully connected.
So in summary if your client is another SQL Server you need to export the cert from the target server. The exported cert needs to be installed on the client with read permissions for the service account. That's it!

Thank you Max for providing me with some direction.